# Conditional code in Verilog in a generate loop

Tags: variables, conditional-statements, verilog

I am trying to encode conditional behavior for Verilog statements in a generate loop. For example, the code below returns an error.

```
module <something> (out);

parameter [4:0] someParam = 0;
output [5:0] out;
genvar l, m;

for(l=0; l<5; l=l+1) begin:STAGE_1
  m = 0;  
  if(someParam[l] < 2)   
    m = l+2;
  else begin  
    m = l-2;
  end
  if (m>16) assign out[l] = 1'b0;  
  else assign out[l] = 1'b1;   
end
endmodule
```

The problem is that the variable `m` is not a constant and the code errors out. Is there any way I can use compile time variable inside a generate statement which would allow some functionality like the variable `m` above?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is missing one end. There are two `begin`s but only one `end`

Comment: There are too algorithmic errors to give a property answer. `(someParam[l] < 2)` is always false, `(m>16)` is always false, `out[5]` is never assigned. No mater the value of `someParam` out will always be `5'bz1111`.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand what you intended to calculate due to some errors in your code.

In general, for you to use a parameter in a statement you can use an always block with a if statement as following:

```
module <something> (out);
parameter [4:0] someParam = 0;
output out;      // in this case out is only one bit. it can be more of course.
integer l,m;     // no need for genver when not using generate

always (*) begin
  m = 0;
  for (l=0; l<5; l=l+1) begin:STAGE_1
    if (someParam[l] == 1'b1) // nothing good comes for checking if a bit is less then 2
      m = m+1;                // just counting bits in someParam. doing +-2 does not make sense.
  end
  if (m >= 3)
     out = 1'b1;
  else
     out = 1'b0;
end
```

The above is a majority function.

Good luck